# display an asp menu consistenly when content page changes?

Tags: html, asp.net

I currently have a treeview menu on my master page so that it remains on screen when the main placeholder is directed to another page. However, my boss wants me to remove it from the master page and put it in its own aspx file. However, once I do that it will no longer be visible once the content page changes. How can I make sure the menu stays on the page if its not on my main master page?

thanks

Comment: can you make it a user control?

Comment: I guess you can move your treeview to a usercontrol and reference the control to each page, it's not idead but at least you are going to reuse the code, do that make any sense?

Comment: I think I understand that. How would I make it into a user control? Oh, I mispoke, its actually not a tree view but a tree data structure I made that spits out <ul> lists. Would that be possible to make into a user control?

Comment: they are ascx files that you can reference into your page as <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Spinner" 
    Src="~/Controls/Spinner.ascx" %>
<html>
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab(v=vs.100).aspx in  your ascx files you can include the html you need you can copy and paste the code and update any references  (js/css/image) if needed